# :first selector checks against parents parent, instead of parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to shuffle large elements inside my layout due to floating them, and trying to display them. Essentially `.gallery-item` with class `.gallery-large` always needs to be first child inside `.item`, there are several `.item` containers inside main `#gallery_slideshow`. At the moment if there is a large item inside second, third etc.. item it gets placed as first element inside first item, where as I want it to stay inside it's own. For example, code below results in 5 elements inside first `.item` with 2 large ones, instead of initial 4 elements with 1 large one.

JS:

```
if($('.gallery-item').length > 1) {
        $('.gallery-large').each(function(e) {
          if(!$(this).is(':first')) {
            $(this).insertBefore('.gallery-item:first');
            //Reset height of owl carousel wrapper in case moved element was last
            $('.owl-wrapper-outer').css('height', 'auto');
          }
        });
      }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery_slideshow" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
              <!-- Example page 1 -->
              <div class="item row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 gallery-item gallery-small">
                  <div class="gallery-image" style="background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg)"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 gallery-item gallery-small">
                  <div class="gallery-image" style="background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg)"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-item gallery-medium">
                  <div class="gallery-image" style="background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg)"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-item gallery-large right">
                  <div class="gallery-image" style="background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg)"></div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Example page 2 -->
              <div class="item row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 gallery-item gallery-small">
                  <div class="gallery-image" style="background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg)"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 gallery-item gallery-small">
                  <div class="gallery-image" style="background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg)"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-item gallery-medium">
                  <div class="gallery-image" style="background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg)"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-item gallery-large right">
                  <div class="gallery-image" style="background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg)"></div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div><!-- END #gallery_slideshow -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do,

```
$(".gallery-large").each(function() {
  $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

1. Loop through each 'gallery-large' item
2. Make it as first child by using `prepend()` method. Prepend it to its own parent to keep the correct context.

Comment: Wow I over complicated it... thank you, this worked, I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed :)

Comment: @Ilja Happy to hear that it helped you:)